# Why kubectl removed command "rolling-update"?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I'm learning kubernetes with book *KubernetesInAction* Ch.09 and make some pratice.

---

I use `kubectl rolling-update kubia-v1 kubia-v2 --image=luksa/kubia:v2`

and he tell me `Error: unknown command "rolling-update" for "kubectl"`

I find it in github [Remove deprecated rolling-update command](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/commit/d3af7e08624bfa7c2f52714b47cfe96a52d15fc0).

I'm confused why they removed this command?

Hope to get an answer, thank you!

Comment: You want to know why it was removed or you are looking for an alternative?

Comment: rolling-update command was completely rewriten because based on https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/61285
it looks like it fixes https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23276

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank U, @Matt ! I think it's not the answer of my question. [Remove deprecated rolling-update command](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/commit/d3af7e08624bfa7c2f52714b47cfe96a52d15fc0) commit at 22/02/2020 but [github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/61285](github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/61285) commit at 2018.

Comment: Hello, @ArghyaSadhu ! I want to know why it was removed.

Comment: According to [Deprecation Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-policy/#deprecating-a-flag-or-cli): "CLI elements of user-facing components (e.g. kubectl) must function after their announced deprecation for no less than: GA: 12 months or 2 releases (whichever is longer) [...]". So it couldn't be removed before 1 year after announced as depricated (in 2018), and is this case it were 2 years (deleted in 2020), so everything seems fine.

Comment: rolling-update is client side logic, rollout is server side logic. They both basically do the same (just in different way) so one must have been removed, because it doesn't make sense to keep duplicated features.

Comment: OOOOH! I understand what you mean.This is the first time I have asked a question here and thank you very much. @Matt : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that in production, you cannot guarantee the network is always stable. If the network lost, you'd end up in a immediate state where different version of pods running together.

Another important thing is that kubernetes is designed for you telling kubernetes the final status and it help you do it. It's not just like this way kubectl need to tell each detailed steps for the upgrade.

So that deployment resource is introduced.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize:

Rolling-update command is client side.
Rollout command is server side and appeared some time after roling-update came out and was meant to solve [some problems](http://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23276) with rolling-update.

They both basically do the same (just in different way) so one must have been removed, because it doesn't make sense to keep duplicated features

---

Answering to your question: *why was is deleted now and after being depricated for some time?*

According to [Deprecation Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-policy/#deprecating-a-flag-or-cli):

> "CLI elements of user-facing components (e.g. kubectl) must function after their announced deprecation for no less than: GA: 12 months or 2 releases (whichever is longer) [...]".

So it couldn't be [removed](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/commit/d3af7e08624bfa7c2f52714b47cfe96a52d15fc0) before 1 year after [announced as depricated](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/61285) (in 2018), and is this case it were 2 years (deleted in 2020), so everything seems fine.